# Get Ip address of a local device from its Mac address

Tags: c, linux, networking, router, arp

I have a local device connected to the router and I can access its Mac address through already existing code. How can I find the IP address of the device using this Mac address in c?

"arp" might be providing the details, but I need it IP address independent from that protocol.

Comment: ARP (Address _Resolution_ Protocol) is what you use to _resolve_ a layer-3 to a layer-2 address, which is the opposite of what you are asking.

Comment: Thnks Ron...I understand that now...but is there any way I can generate IP address from its Mac address...?Kindly guide me in this

Comment: That could be a problem because an interface to which the MAC address is tied may have multiple IP addresses assigned. How are you going to determine which one?

Comment: @StephenC, neither of those does that. Also, RARP has been obsolete for many years.

Comment: Only way to do that without scanning the network with ARP queries is to keep track of what combination  of MAC and IP address is hitting the router. The OS already keep track of that in the ARP table as mentioned by others. Notice you don't have to use ARP protocol at all, the information is made available in a plain text format in `/proc/net/arp` and the list is populated automatically by the system as it makes contact with new peers.

Comment: @Havenard, the ARP table is populated by ARP, so if the point is to be independent of ARP, then that fails. The ARP table is actually part of ARP, and it is addressed in the RFC for ARP.

Comment: @RonMaupin Who cares?

Comment: Please don't ask for a tutorial. You should ask a specific question for a particular programming problem. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your requirements allow you to make use of ARP *indirectly* (that is, by relying on standard networking behavior rather than coding ARP queries yourself)...

Your best answer is probably to find the MAC address in your local ARP cache, as exposed in `/proc/net/arp`.  Of course, there's only going to be data there for your device if your host has recently seen traffic from it on the network.

[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86165/can-one-ping-a-nic-by-mac) has some suggestions for dealing with that situation: basically, run some sort of network scan to generate traffic to *every* ip address on your network, and then mine your local ARP table for the answer.

Comment: First, that is actually using ARP, which the question forbids. Second, how do you decide on which IP address to choose if the MAC address has several attached to it?

Comment: (a) it doesn't require coding arp queries yourself, so unless this is a homework assignment I think we're safe, although the OP seems better able to address that question than either you or I, and (b) you would either need to have a ui to allow the user to pick, or you would need assume that any address is valid and just pick one, or you would need to come up with some other method to make that determination.  Since there's no guarantee that a device has a single ip address this is always a possibility.

Comment: All I see is that the question says it must be independent of ARP. Using the ARP table is dependent on, not independent of, ARP.

Comment: I guess we'll let the OP worry about that.